# asp.net - Please show me a example of find method of dataview control

Tags: asp.net, find, dataview

I am trying to find in DataView but can't.
please show me alternative if any..

```
   string conString =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aspDB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText:"select * from name", 
    connection: con);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);       
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Customers");
    adapter.Fill(ds,"Customers");
    DataView dv;
    dv= new DataView(ds.Tables[0],"","id desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
   var find = dv.Find("abc");

    if (find == -1)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('No Match')</script>");        
    }
    else 
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Match Found')</script>");
    }
```

Comment: Please user RowFilter in DataView

Comment: Tried RowFilter too..but error is :System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: It finely works with int type value, but when passing string type Exception occurs